# How to tell MakeMaker to build XS files in a subdirectory?

Tags: perl, xs, makemaker

I've got a largish project to which I've just added some XS code, and I'd like to keep the top-level directory as clean as possible. I want to put the XS file and typemap et al. into a subdirectory, but if I do, MakeMaker can't find them. So right now, they're just sitting out in the project root.

How to I tell MakeMaker to look in a subdirectory for the XS stuff so it can be built from there?

Comment: @schwern - Thanks for your answer - I completely missed that option in the EUMM docs. I just want to add, I ended up switching to [Module::Build](http://metacpan.org/module/Module::Build) anyway because [Module::Build::WithXSpp](http://metacpan.org/module/Module::Build::WithXSpp) made a bunch of other things *much* easier. And switching was also easy because I'm using [Dist::Zilla](http://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla). The [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ModuleBuild::Custom](http://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ModuleBuild::Custom) module helped a whole lot, too! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you put the `.xs` files into the `lib` directory, MakeMaker will find them.

You can explicitly tell MakeMaker where the `.xs` files and what `.c` file to translate it into using the `XS` option to `WriteMakefile`.

```
WriteMakefile(
    NAME    => "Foo::Bar",
    XS      => {
        "lib/Foo/Bar.xs" => "lib/Foo/Bar.c",
    }
);
```